# Using wh_shell hook for custom windows-shell(explorer.exe replacement program) C++

Tags: c++, windows, windows-shell

So I have spent that past week and a half working on code to simply setup the hook procedure for wh_shell for a program that will replace explorer.exe in the registry and will run as the main desktop program. There seems to be very little information and sources for using this outside of just the windows API which is a bit undescriptive and doesn't explain everything to a great detail. For some reason I just cant get it to work, no matter if I run it inside of explorer.exe, or if I replace the register and make it the default shell. I'm going to ask a couple of things in this post because I think that if you can answer one of these questions you likely have the answer to more.

So first I just have a question about hooks in general: When I run the SetWindowsHookEx(...) function -resource below- it says for var *lpfn* that a dll is not necessary if the hook is only used to monitor the current process. Now obviously when monitoring events such as window_created, those are events within a different processes which makes me think that the hookproc has to be within a DLL(which is how ive programmed so far). But this is questionable to me because when u are running SetWindowsHookEx(...) the process I wish to monitor do not yet exist until the user decides to start them. Do these processes notify the system when wh_shell events are being done so that I my hook doesnt need to get placed into every process upon creation, or is it more like when I run SetWindowsHookEx(...) with wh_shell that it will place a hook in all processes when the are created. The second resource states that the system just calls the hookproc when these things happen, so then do I even need a DLL, or what process does it need to be hooked to because I dont think it needs to be hooked into everything.

So second I have a question regarding setting my process as default shell - see resources - the resource states any process that registers itself as the default shell(which I assume is just modifying the registry to my process, if not and there is more please let me know) needs to call the SystemsParameterInfo(...) function. So first, does this func need to be called before running SetWindowsHookEx(...) or is there some expected spot it should be elsewhere in my code? Then in regards to the other variables it doesnt specify for, just curious what the recommended would be to set them as, like what are they set as for explorer.exe, and maybe a few other examples(including things NOT to do).

Finally for the sake of testing, using the console will be the most helpful to me here. The console will be used for input to run functions and commands for now(like open the register and swap back the shell to explorer.exe). If my hookproc is within a DLL, I need it to output some messages, I dont want to muddle the same console and I also dont even know if it will output to the same console, so what might be a recommended or potential solution for outputs(again this is temporary and for testing so it doesnt have to be perfect or even great)?

Also I would think windows 11 shouldn't be an issue, but I havent tested on windows 10 system...

I havent included any code as Im pretty sure most of this stuff can be answered without it and that its so few lines of code that its not like typical questions where its like examine my code and help me, maybe some example code you can show me would be really helpful.

Thankyou!

SetWindowsHookEx(...)

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa

defaultShell

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks#wh_shell
- regards to WH_SHELL section

Testing Environment:

- Windows 11 vm running in Hyper-V Manager

Comment: _"...A global hook procedure can be called in the context of any application in the same desktop as the calling thread, so the procedure must be in a separate DLL module. ..._" [Hooks Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks)  ie your DLL is injected into each process and called in the context of that process by the Operating System when processing a hook

Comment: SetWindowsHookEx is used by other processes, the shell gets them from somewhere else (undocumented).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned an important parameter in your description and that is the last argument of SetWindowsHookEx, the thread id.
When it is set to 0 then ..
'[in] Specifies the identifier of the thread with which the hook procedure is to be associated. If this parameter is zero, the hook procedure is associated with all existing threads running in the same desktop as the calling thread.'

That said, then like everything in Windows programming nothing is as what the documentation states, its as if the documentation is a wish-list Microsoft will like Windows to be when it grows up.

Actually even if you manage to get everything right you will see that the shell messages you will get will be VERY few compared to what the documentation states.

I am working on the same issue and when I get it going I will post the results here.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32092730)